# Does Github still allow private raw file access with PAT in URL

Tags: github-api

I used to be able to make the following call with a Personal Access Token (the classic token)

```bash
curl https://$PAT@raw.githubusercontent.com/$ORG/$REPO/master/$FILE
```

But now I just get the Github default 404 response.

If I follow a different approach the the file is accessible.

```bash
curl -H 'Authorization: token $PAT' \
-H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' \
-O -L https://api.github.com/$ORG/$REPO/master/$FILE
```

I can't find anything in the docs that states the old curl URL request has been removed. Has this method now been removed?

Comment: [Github's support system](https://docs.github.com/en/support/contacting-github-support/creating-a-support-ticket) may get better results.

Comment: They have recently-ish [disabled password authentication](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-12-git-password-authentication-is-shutting-down/), but I see nothing in the docs that says you can't use a token in the URL any longer. (I also don't see anything that says you can, though ;))

Comment: And FWIW, it still works for me. You don't have a special character in one of the variables, per chance? Double quoting would help in that case.

Comment: This is strange, I have tried on a variety of different machines and created a new token to test it, without any joy